# Is merging from remote branch or local branch technically the same?

Tags: git, merge

Let me explain the question with an example.

Let us say, I create a new branch from my `master` and push it to `origin` so as to create a remote branch at `origin/mybranch`.

Next I make changes in this branch, stage, commit & push.

Now, I wish to merge that commit to `master`. For simplicity, let us assume there are no other changes/commits in any of the branches apart from the one that I specified.

My question is: would the following two commands lead to the exact same state (in my local `master` branch):

1. `git merge origin/mybranch`
2. `git merge mybranch`

I didn't know how else to phrase this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A branch in git is just a human-friendly symbolic name of a commit. So, if branches point to the same commit - the result of merge will be identical. You also could do `git merge <commit_id>`.

The only noticeable difference is a default message text of the merge commit if any (and you could edit it if you want).